# Write a json dictionary to pdf as a table

Tags: json, html, pdf, jspdf

I have a dictionary of objects with over 2000 items, e.g.:

```
{
      {"ID":1, "Name":"one", "IsKey":true},
      {"ID":2, "Name":"two", "IsKey":false},
      {"ID":3, "Name":"three", "IsKey":false},
      ......
      {"ID":2500, "Name":"million", "IsKey":true},
}
```

And I want to create a multi-page PDF that will look like the following:

[image]

Currently I'm using jsPDF to do this but the page is not looking as I want it to look like.

```
let doc: any = new jsPDF();
doc.setLineWidth(1000);
let items = this.getItems();

let pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;

// Before adding new content
let y = 0; // Height position of new content
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    doc.text(0, y, JSON.stringify(items[i]));
    if (y >= pageHeight - 10) {
        doc.addPage();
        y = -1; // Restart height position
    }
    y += 10;
}

doc.save('myTest.pdf');
```